# What is establishment-level data

Tags: productivity

National level or aggregate level data and firm-level data are self explanatory. I have seen certain papers on productivity analysis as well as other topics which refer to "establishment-level" data. Can someone please explain what is meant by this term?

Answer (score 3):

Establishments are firms at the facility level. Think about it like branches: If a firm has three different branches, each of these branches counts as an establishment. If a firm has no branches, the firm itself is the (sole) establishment.

Answer (score 2):

Economic data for businesses are usually constructed at the establishment level, the firm level, or the enterprise level. An establishment is a single physical location where one predominant activity occurs. A firm is an establishment or a combination of establishments and, for the purposes of this article, is defined by its unique Employer Identification number (EIN) issued by the Internal Revenue Service (IRS). Firms operate in one industry or in multiple industries. An enterprise is a firm or a combination of firms that engages in economic activities which are classified into multiple industries. An enterprise may report under one or a number of EINs.

[Source](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2016/article/establishment-firm-or-enterprise.htm)